# convert HTML to XHTML using TagSoup in bash

Tags: html, bash, xhtml, tag-soup

I was under the impression you can convert HTML to XHTML using TagSoup. I have the tagsoup jar file saved as tagsoup.jar I used the following command `wget -O usa_stock.html "http://markets.usatoday.com/custom/usatoday-com/new/html-mktscreener.asp#" | java -jar tagsoup.jar usa_stock.html` When I use this command, it generates both the html and xhtml file but when I open the xhtml in firefox it's empty. I'm suspecting that when I pipeline it just doesn't know which file I was trying to convert.

Can someone help me out with this one?

Thanks.

Comment: have you confirmed `java -jar tagsoup.jar <usa_stock.html> usa_stockx.xhtml` works with existing file?

Comment: I did a minor edit. It creates an .xhtml with xhtml encoding. However, I noticed that it doesn't always generate for the entire html that was passed. It can either create an empty or half the xhtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipeline (`|`) used in your code is wrong for sure, change it with `&&` could possible solve your problem.

1. As the `wget` didn't output the retrieve webpage to `stdout`, so you piped nothing into tagsoup.
2. Although you also specified input file and output file for jsoup, you used pipeline. so at the time `java-jar` starts to execute, `wget` is still running. The input file you specified for tagsoup isn't ready yet.

So you need `wget` quit with `0` exit status first before jsoup start, `&&` here will serve this purpose.